# Invisible fonts in Firefox

Tags: bug, status-completed, css

Something about the site's CSS/whatever is causing lots of text to not render in recent (nightly) versions of Firefox on OSX 10.6.  Most conspicuously the main site's list of questions.  Here is a [screenshot of the behavior](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CgH8P.png).

- The version I'm using is  `Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.6; rv:25.0) Gecko/20130723 Firefox/25.0`
- The meta site is ok
- Other stackexchange sites I've checked also have no problems.
- It works in Chrome, and the most recent stable version of Firefox
- The problem persists in safe mode
- I can click on links and copy the text, it simply doesn't show up.

This might well be a bug in Firefox, but figured I'd better report this here, since I don't have any knowledge of how the site is styled.  (And thus would not have much to say in a bug report.)  :)

*e:* It was [this bug](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=896592), and is now fixed in Nightly Firefox builds.

The bug report suggests that the @font-face declaration is technically incorrect, because you're not supposed to list multiple src descriptors.

> I notice that the CSS being used on mtv.de to load the fonts (the file fonts.css) is incorrect. The @font-face rules include a src: descriptor with a data-URL woff font, but then they have a second src: descriptor with the data-URL (uncompressed) truetype data, which overrides the woff one. As such, the truetype data is always used, and the woff data, although included in the file, is worthless.
>
> The correct way to provide multiple formats within a @font-face rule is to list multiple resources within a -single- src: descriptor (as the fonts.css file does for the truetype and svg formats). Then the browser should use the first supported one it finds in the list. So if you have some kind of contact with the site, you might like to offer this feedback.

I'm pretty sure rpg.se's CSS is also doing this.  Whether this actually matters, I leave to someone who knows more about this.  :)

Comment: Do you have any problem in stable versions of FF?

Comment: Could you post a screenshot?

Comment: I added a screenshot.  I don't see this in a stable version of Firefox -- it's probably a Firefox bug, but I was hoping someone here might have some idea what's special about the invisible text.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firefox's Nightly builds appear to be having trouble with RPG.SE's web font, *Lusitana Regular*.

The visible areas of the site you're seeing are using fonts like Palantino, Times New Roman, Georgia or your default serif font. All the invisible areas use Lusitana Regular.

This indicates a bug in the Nightly builds. It also may indicate a shift in how Firefox is going to handle web fonts in the future. Firefox can't just drop being backwards compatible with how web fonts currently work, though, so the fact that web font text isn't showing up is a bug in Nightly.

Comment: Yup, a Firefox bug, though apparently there's something incorrect about the CSS that's triggering it.  (See my edit to the question)